# Convert sql php script to coldfusion

Tags: php, coldfusion

we have a script that has been provided from our developers for php to generate a best sellers list from our database, however we need it to be in coldfusion!

Is there a simple way to convert or will this need rewriting completely?

Thanks in advance for any advice :-)

```
// // ---------- // Get Top Selling Products (by sku) // ---------- // 
    function CWgetBestSelling($max_products=5, $sub_ids=0)
    {
        $productQuery = '';
        $returnQuery = '';
        $idList = '0';
        $itemsToAdd = '';

        if (!is_numeric($idList[0])) {
                $idList = '0';
        }   
        $q_productQuery = mysql_query( "
        SELECT count(*) as prod_counter,
        p.product_id,
        p.product_name,
        p.product_preview_description,
        p.product_date_modified
        FROM cw_products p
        INNER JOIN cw_order_skus o
        INNER JOIN cw_skus s
        WHERE o.ordersku_sku = s.sku_id
        AND s.sku_product_id = p.product_id
        AND NOT p.product_on_web = 0
        AND NOT p.product_archive = 1
        AND NOT s.sku_on_web = 0
        GROUP BY product_id
        ORDER BY prod_counter DESC
          LIMIT ".$max_products
        ,$_ENV["request.cwapp"]["db_link"]);
        $productQuery = array();
        while ($qd = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_productQuery)) {
            $productQuery[] = $qd;
        }

    // add values to list
        foreach ($productQuery as $values) {
            $idList = $values['product_id'] . "," . $idList;
        }
        // if not enough results, fill in from sub_ids 
        if (count($productQuery) < $max_products) {
                // number needed 
                $itemsToAdd = $max_products - count($productQuery);
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $itemsToAdd; $i++) {
                    if (substr_count($sub_ids, ',') >= $i) { 
                        $idListArray = explode(',', $sub_ids);
                        $idList .= "," . $idListArray[$i];
                    }
                }   
                $q_resultsQuery = mysql_query("
                SELECT 0 as prod_counter,
                p.product_id,
                p.product_name,
                p.product_preview_description,
                p.product_date_modified
                FROM cw_products p
                WHERE p.product_id in(".CWqueryParam($idList).")
                AND NOT p.product_on_web = 0
                AND NOT p.product_archive = 1
                ORDER BY product_date_modified DESC
                ",$_ENV["request.cwapp"]["db_link"]);
        } else {
            $q_resultsQuery = mysql_query("
                SELECT count(*) as prod_counter,
                p.product_id,
                p.product_name,
                p.product_preview_description,
                p.product_date_modified
                FROM cw_products p
                INNER JOIN cw_order_skus o
                INNER JOIN cw_skus s
                WHERE o.ordersku_sku = s.sku_id
                AND s.sku_product_id = p.product_id
                AND NOT p.product_on_web = 0
                AND NOT p.product_archive = 1
                AND NOT s.sku_on_web = 0
                GROUP BY product_id
                ORDER BY prod_counter DESC, product_date_modified
            ",$_ENV["request.cwapp"]["db_link"]);

        }
    while ($qd = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_resultsQuery)) {
            $returnQuery[] = $qd;
        }
        return $returnQuery;

    }
```

Comment: you have to rewrite the code to `coldfusion`

Comment: You need to rewrite the code, perhaps the only part you can reuse is the SQL queries, but I never have used coldfusion.

Comment: A good place to start would be http://learncfinaweek.com/

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will look at extracting the sql and working on the query...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code conversion questions don't tend to stay open long because they're viewed as lazy.  So, Here are some references to get you started. I'm no PHP pro but after a quick glance at your code I think this list of links will give you a good head start.

- [CFFunction](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_21.html)
- [CFQuery](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_17.html)
- [CFArgument](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_a-b_6.html)
- [valueList()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_13.html)
- [CFLoop](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_j-l_10.html)
- [CFif](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_i_01.html)

In the interest of not doing your work for you and give you the opportunity to learn, I'll provide some samples but not the entire code so you get an idea where your PHP fits into CF. This is also the tag version, not the script version.

```
<cffunction name = "CWgetBestSelling" ...>
  <cfargument name = "max_products" default = "5" ...>
  <cfargument ...>

  <cfset var local.productQuery = "">
  <cfset var local.returnQuery = "">
  <cfset ...>
  <cfset ...>

  <cfquery name = "q_productQuery " datasource = "yourDatasource">
    SELECT 
      count(*) as prod_counter,
      p.product_id,
      p.product_name,
      p.product_preview_description,
      p.product_date_modified
    FROM 
      cw_products p
      INNER JOIN cw_order_skus o
      INNER JOIN cw_skus s
    WHERE 
          o.ordersku_sku = s.sku_id
      AND s.sku_product_id = p.product_id
      AND NOT p.product_on_web = 0
      AND NOT p.product_archive = 1
      AND NOT s.sku_on_web = 0
    GROUP BY 
      product_id
    ORDER BY 
      prod_counter DESC
    LIMIT #arguments.max_products#
  </cfquery>

  ...
  ...
  ... 

  <cfreturn yourReturnVariable>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, I just need some guidance being a noob! I would rather find out how to do it rather than get someone else to do it...Much obliged Travis I will read up...